# how to check avro schema registry usage

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro, akka-stream, avro4s

I am using avro through avro4s.
This is my configuration for consumer/producer

```
 def producerSettings(system: ActorSystem): ProducerSettings[String, Array[Byte]] = ProducerSettings(
    system,
    new StringSerializer,
    new ByteArraySerializer)
    .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
    .withProperty("key.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer")
    .withProperty("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer")
    .withProperty("key.converter.schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081")
    .withProperty("value.converter.schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081")
    .withProperty("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081")
    .withProperty("auto.create.topics.enable", "true")

  def consumerSettings(system: ActorSystem): ConsumerSettings[String, Array[Byte]] =
    ConsumerSettings(
      system,
      new StringDeserializer,
      new ByteArrayDeserializer)
      .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
      .withProperty("key.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer")
      .withProperty("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer")
      .withProperty("key.converter.schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081")
      .withProperty("value.converter.schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081")
      .withProperty("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081")
      .withGroupId("test")
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
```

I have doubts that the registers are used.
When my application is running it is silence in the schema registry logs.

How can i check that my application is use the registry?

And if it is not - how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong classes, so your properties will likely have errors

You actually need to use `KafkaAvroSerializer` for the Producer here

```
new StringSerializer,
new ByteArraySerializer)
```

And `KafkaAvroDeserializer` for the consumer here

```
new StringDeserializer,
new ByteArrayDeserializer)
```

And try to change `String, Array[Byte]` to `GenericRecord` or some case-class you made from Avro4s